# My form is not sending data correctly using Ajax, how can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to send the data that is in the form to my database using Ajax and depending on the action of the button it will execute the url I need, but It doesn't seem to be working because It only sends zero like as if the form were completely empty

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" id="form_shirt" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  ID:
  <br>
  <input type="hidden" name="id_shirt" id="id_shirt" class="form-control"> Name:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="name_shirt" id="name_shirt" class="form-control" required="required"> Price:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="price_shirt" id="price_shirt" class="form-control" required="required">

  <button id="insert_shirt" class="submit" name="btninsert" id="btninsert" value="Insert" />
  <button id="update_shirt" class="submit" name="btnupdate" id="btnupdate" value="Update" />
  <button id="delete_shirt" class="submit" name="btndelete" id="btndelete" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.submit').on("click", function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.id + ".php",
      method: "POST",
      data: $('#form_shirt').serialize(),
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(data) {
        $('#form_shirt)[0].reset();
        $('#table_shirt').html(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "shirts");

 $output = '';
    $name_shirt = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["name_shirt"]);  
    $price_shirt = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["price_shirt"]);  

    $query = "INSERT into shirts ( name, price)
    VALUES ('$name_shirt','$price_shirt') ";
    if(mysqli_query($connect, $query))
    {
     $output .= '<label class="text-success">Data Inserted</label>';
     $select_query = "SELECT id_shirt, name, price FROM shirts";
     $result = mysqli_query($connect, $select_query);
     $output .= '
      <table id="shirts" class="table table-bordered">  
                   <thead>
                    <tr>  
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>NAME</th>
                        <th>PRICE</th>
                    </tr>
</thead>
     ';
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
      $output .= '
       <tr>  
       <tbody>
                         <td>' . $row["id_shirt"] . '</td>
                         <td>' . $row["name"] . '</td>
                         <td>' . $row["price"] . '</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
      ';
     }
     $output .= '</table>';
    }
    echo $output;

?>
```

Comment: can you console.log($('#form_shirt').serialize()) to see

Comment: I don't think you need processData wit POST and remove the contantType to use the default, you are sending a form.

Comment: I've already done that, and it does shows the values that are in the form but by the time it is sent it shows 0

Comment: $('#form_shirt)[0].reset(); is this a typo in question only? Missing '

Comment: @atomSmasher Sorry, my mistake, when I copied the code I changed the name of the #id and I forgot the double quotes, but that is not the problem that I'm struggling with

Comment: what about adding dataType:"text" to your ajax call?

Comment: also would check your ajax contentType member. You are setting it to false in the ajax call but passing multipart/form-data in the html.

Comment: Are you sure you are processing/extracting the serialized data correctly server-side?

Comment: **Sidenote:** In your PHP, your `<tr>` and `<tbody>` are in the wrong order. Also, `<tbody>` (and its closing-tag) should be placed *outside* the `while-loop`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that all your `button`s have their `id` declared twice?

```
<button id="insert_shirt" class="submit" name="btninsert" id="btninsert" value="Insert" />
```

This may very well be the cause for your misfire, because it will try to POST to a URL that doesn't exist, returning an empty value.

Also, `button`s have both opening and closing tags.
I think the line below should be sufficient for your goal:

```
<button type="button" id="insert_shirt" class="submit">Insert</button>
```

- I added `type="button"`. If you don't declare a [type](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp), the browser will choose for you, and since the button is inside a form, it will probably become `type="submit"`, which you don't want because you're using Ajax.
  *In the codepen below I didn't add a type, and as you can see the form is submitted when you click one of the buttons.*
- I removed both `name="btninsert"` and `value="Insert"`, I assume you don't use the `value` in you PHP script, which probably means you also don't need the `name`.

Check this pen to see it in action: **https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MoNXYj?editors=1010**
*(You can actually use the buttons, CodePen will simulate the submit action for you)*

---

### UPDATE

This may be a bit naive and/or ignorant of me, but if you're still having problems a simpler solution might be to change your set-up a bit so that all elements and code work in the same form-submitting-type-direction. You are now using *elements for sync submitting* and counteracting that with *code for async submitting*.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="form_shirt">
  <input type="hidden" name="id_shirt" id="id_shirt" class="form-control"><br>
  Name: <input type="text" name="name_shirt" id="name_shirt" class="form-control" required="required"><br>
  Price: <input type="text" name="price_shirt" id="price_shirt" class="form-control" required="required">
  <br><br>
  <button type="button" id="insert_shirt" class="submit">Insert</button>
  <button type="button" id="update_shirt" class="submit">Update</button>
  <button type="button" id="delete_shirt" class="submit">Delete</button>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.submit').on("click",function() {
    $.post(this.id+".php", {
      id_shirt: $('#id_shirt').val(),
      name_shirt: $('#name_shirt').val(),
      price_shirt: $('#price_shirt').val()
    }, function(data) {
      $('#form_shirt .form-control').val("");
      $('#table_shirt').html(data);
    });
  });
});
```

**codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bRXKaV?editors=1011**
*(Note that this will not produce any output, because there is no form submitted, only the Ajax POST to a URL that doesn't exist and therefor doesn't return a response)*

Comment: I thought that would solve the issue but once I edited my code, the button does nothing :/

Comment: @HeberSolis Did you remove `value="Insert"` from the button? And did you remove the right `id` ? Is your php script called `insert_shirt.php` or `btninsert.php` (ok, fairly sure it's the first one, just making sure:).

Comment: @HeberSolis Also check if the `id` that you removed isn't used anywhere else in your application (you are serializing the whole form and sending that as data, maybe in php you're still trying to reference the button by the `id` that was removed?).

Comment: @HeberSolis And may I presume that you did already look at the comment under your question about `contentType` to be sure that is set up correctly? Same goes maybe for `processData`, I have no experience with those settings.

Comment: I edited my code and now it throws the error  Undefined index: name_shirt in C:\xampp\htdocs\admon2x\insert_shirt.php on line 6 I've added my php code in my question, thank you so much for your help

Comment: @HeberSolis Did you have a look at my updated answer? Did you edit your code to the code under UPDATE? If so, I really don't understand how `$_POST["name_shirt"]` can be undefined, it truly baffles me. *If you haven't done that yet, give that a try and see if it works. We can always try to roll back your code as much as possible afterwards, but then at least we know if this works or not.

Comment: I truly appreciate your help, and all the time you took to help me, but sadly it doesn't work yet :/

Comment: @HeberSolis Change `method: "POST",` to `type: "POST"` in ajax call and test it.

Comment: @HeberSolis Best thing you can do now is to dial everything back to a minimum to find out where the problem is. **JS:** `$(document).ready(function(){ $.post('insert_shirt.php',{test:'imatest'},function(data){console.log(data);}); });`. **insert_shirt.php:** `<?php echo 'posted: '.$_POST['test'];?>`. Strip all other code, just for the test, and run it (press F12 to open DevTools > Console). Just refresh the page and the console should show the test value. If this doesn't work, there's something else going on. If this does work, you can add your code piece by piece to find where it goes wrong.